# How to use bluetooth keyboard with both Android and WIndows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, bluetooth, android

I purchased this [Logitech bluetooth keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009JPBPWO) which, according to the specifications on the page, can switch between both Android and Windows 8 devices. I haven't figured out how to do this. Is a specific type of bluetooth USB adapter required? And even assuming I had the necessary USB adapter, what commands must be executed (on the keyboard, Android, or Windows 8 machines) for the bluetooth keyboard to switch between devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That keyboard like most bluetooth input devices [only supports pairing one device at a time](http://www.amazon.com/does-support-multipairing-multiple-devices/forum/Fx312UOX9H11U32/Tx3V4IPD4BYT47W/1). You'll have to repair each time you switch between devices.

[The Logitech K810 keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0099SMFVQ) and [K811](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0099SMFP2) let you pair up to 3 devices at a time and switch using the dedicated buttons. There also some other keyboards with this feature.

Also any modern bluetooth keyboard should be OS agnostic, don't read too much into the marketing hype. (On a personal note, I would go with a USB RF dongle like Logitech's "Unifying" one instead of bluetooth for laptops and desktops)